# Checkered / square-patterned copper plane on a PCB

Tags: pcb-layers, ground-plane

The Verge [has published](https://www.theverge.com/2019/3/19/18263844/apple-iphone-prototype-m68-original-development-board-red) photos of the original iPhone "dev kit".

The board looks like an ordinary development kit to me, however there is a strange pattern of squares on the topmost layer. I know only of solid and hatched variants of a copper plane.

**What could be the reasons to use such a pattern on a copper plane?**

Aesthetics? EMC? Obfuscation?

[image]

Comment: There are a few duplicates of this question